# Python DataFrame: split to lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I've a `DataFrame` df of let us say one thousand rows, and I'd like to split it to 10 lists where each list contains a DataFrame of 100 rows. So list

```
zero = df[0:99]
one  = df[100:199]
two  = df[200:299]
...
nine = df[900:900]
```

What could be a good (preferably) oneliner for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
list_of_dfs = [df.loc[i:i+size-1,:] for i in range(0, len(df),1000)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming index is a running integer (can use .reset_index() if not)

```
[d for g,d in df.groupby(df.index//100)]
```

Returns a list of dataframes.